# Number of ways to arrange nesting dolls

Tags: combinatorics

You have a set of 6 Russian nesting dolls, and they are in increasing size. How many different nestings of the dolls are there, given that in a nesting there must be at least two dolls used and they must be nested in the order from smallest in the center to the largest on the outside?

I solved this problem going case by case, enumerating the nestings with 2 dolls, then three dolls, until 6, but this was tedious and I was wondering if there was a more elegant solution. Thank you!

Comment: and how many different nestings did you get?

Comment: Start with finding all possible nestings and subtract the number of nestings that are forbidden.

Comment: 15 nestings  of 2 + 20 of 3+ 15 of 4 + 6 of 5+ 1 of 6 = 57 total nestings

Comment: @dphil1 Correct because $2^6-\binom60-\binom61=64-1-6=57$ (applying the method suggested in my former comment).